# COPY command in cassandar in docker return error;Failed to import 0 rows: IOError - Can't open 'fma_dataset.csv' for r eading: no matching file found

Tags: docker, csv, import, cassandra, cqlsh

I want import data from csv to keyspace in cassandra in docker. So I use this command step by step:

```
docker run --name my-cassandra --network some-network -d cassandra:latest
docker cp fma_dataset.csv my-cassandra:fma_dataset.csv
docker run -it --network some-network --rm cassandra cqlsh my-cassandra
CREATE KEYSPACE fma
           WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1};
CREATE TABLE fma_test (
track_id text PRIMARY key,
title_track text,
date_released text,
title_album text,
artist text,
duration text,
genre text,
favorites_artist text,
listens_track text,
favorites_track text,
listens_album text,
favorites_album text,
);

COPY fma_test 
(track_id,title_track,date_released,title_album,artist,duration,genre,favorites_artist,listens_track,favorites_track,listens_album,favorites_album) 
FROM 'fma_dataset.csv' WITH HEADER=TRUE;
 But I get this error: 
Failed to import 0 rows: IOError - Can't open 'fma_dataset.csv' for reading: no
matching file found,  given up after 1 attempts
```

I need to remind you that the file is in the container and has been copied correctly in the path.
please help; Thanks

Comment: Are u certain about the existence of the file at the same location ?  check permissions in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a mount point with -v, which points to your server/computer.
There you can transfer the file more easily.
Example:
docker run --name my-cassandra --network some-network -v /path/on/your/server:/path/in/your/docker/container -d cassandra:latest

This way Cassandra can access all files of this location (of course the permissions of the files should be set accordingly). After deleting the container, these files are also preserved (I would always recommend this if the service is to go live).

Many greetings